# tidyr::unite across column patterns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataset that looks something like this

```
site <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
D01_1 <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
D01_2 <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
D02_1 <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
D02_2 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
D03_1 <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
D03_2 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(site, D01_1, D01_2, D02_1, D02_2, D03_1, D03_2)
```

I am trying to unite the `D0x_1` and `D0x_2` columns so that the values in the columns are separated by a slash. I can do this with the following code and it works just fine:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df.unite <- df %>%
  unite(D01, D01_1, D01_2, sep = "/", remove = TRUE) %>%
  unite(D02, D02_1, D02_2, sep = "/", remove = TRUE) %>%
  unite(D03, D03_1, D03_2, sep = "/", remove = TRUE)
```

...but the problem is that it requires me to type out each `unite` pair multiple times and it is unwieldy across the large number of columns in my dataset. Is there a way in `dplyr` to unite across similarly patterned column names and then loop across the columns? `unite_each` doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options, which are really the same thing rearranged.

---

### Option 1. Nested calls

First, you can use `lapply` to apply `unite_` (the standard evaluation version to which you can pass strings) programmatically across columns. To do so, you'll need to build a list of names for it to use, and then wrap the `lapply` in `do.call(cbind` to catch columns, and `cbind` `site` back to it. Altogether:

```
cols <- unique(substr(names(df)[-1], 1, 3))
cbind(site = df$site, do.call(cbind,
        lapply(cols, function(x){unite_(df, x, grep(x, names(df), value = TRUE), 
                                        sep = '/', remove = TRUE) %>% select_(x)})
        ))

#   site D01 D02 D03
# 1    A 1/1 1/0 1/0
# 2    B 0/1 0/1 1/1
# 3    C 0/0 1/0 0/0
# 4    D 0/1 0/0 0/0
# 5    E 1/1 1/1 0/1
```

---

### Option 2: Chained

Alternately, if you really like pipes, you can actually hack the whole thing into a chain (`lapply` included!), swapping out a few of the base functions for `dplyr` ones:

```
df %>% select(-site) %>% names() %>% substr(1,3) %>% unique() %>%
  lapply(function(x){unite_(df, x, grep(x, names(df), value = TRUE), 
                            sep = '/', remove = TRUE) %>% select_(x)}) %>%
  bind_cols() %>% mutate(site = as.character(df$site)) %>% select(site, starts_with('D'))

# Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
# 
#    site   D01   D02   D03
#   (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr)
# 1     A   1/1   1/0   1/0
# 2     B   0/1   0/1   1/1
# 3     C   0/0   1/0   0/0
# 4     D   0/1   0/0   0/0
# 5     E   1/1   1/1   0/1
```

Check out the intermediate products to see how it fits together, but it's pretty much the same logic as the base approach.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for this and for the instruction as well - it's a great to learn how to do things in R more effectively!

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution with base functions. First, I looked for indexes of ***_1 in columns. I also created names for columns for the final process, using `gsub()` and `unique()`. The sapply part pastes two columns with `/`. If x = 1, then, x +1 = 2. So you always choose two columns next to each other and handle the pasting job. Then, I added `site` with `cbind()` and created a data frame. The last job is to assign column names.

```
library(magrittr)

ind <- grep(pattern = "1$", x = names(df))

names <- unique(gsub(pattern = "_\\d+$",
                replacement = "", x = names(df)))

sapply(ind, function(x){
        foo <- paste(df[,x], df[, x+1], sep = "/")
        foo
       }) %>%
cbind(as.character(df$site), .) %>%
data.frame -> out

names(out) <- names

#  site D01 D02 D03
#1    A 1/1 1/0 1/0
#2    B 0/1 0/1 1/1
#3    C 0/0 1/0 0/0
#4    D 0/1 0/0 0/0
#5    E 1/1 1/1 0/1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an easy base R approach, too:

```
cols <- split(names(df)[-1], sub("_\\d+", "", names(df)[-1]))

cbind(df[1], sapply(names(cols), function(col) {
  do.call(paste, c(df[cols[[col]]], sep = "/"))
}))
#  site D01 D02 D03
#1    A 1/1 1/0 1/0
#2    B 0/1 0/1 1/1
#3    C 0/0 1/0 0/0
#4    D 0/1 0/0 0/0
#5    E 1/1 1/1 0/1
```