# Create (dplyr::mutate) and select (dplyr::select) new variables that paste two existing columns by means of a user-defined function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, paste

Using a user-defined function I have to join the lower and higher bound of confidence intervals (named as `CIlow` and `CIhigh`) of a selected number of columns from a data frame. The data frame has `CIlow` and `CIhigh` for a number of groups (named as `a`, `b` and `c`) and for a number row (in this example just two). See below how the data frame looks like.

```
dataframe<-data.frame(CIlow_a=c(1.1,1.2),CIlow_b=c(2.1,2.2),CIlow_c=c(3.1,3.2),
CIhigh_a=c(1.3,1.4),CIhigh_b=c(2.3,2.4),CIhigh_c=c(3.3,3.4))
```

I would like to have a joined column for each group in a selected number of groups (e.g. `a`, `b`) among the existing ones (`a`, `b` and `c`).

Thus, the expected output should be the following:

```
output<-data.frame(CI_a=c("(1.1,1.3)","(1.2,1.4)"),
                  CI_b=c("(2.1,2.3)","(2.2,2.4)"))
```

To built my own user-defined function I tried the following code:

```
f<-function(df,gr){

enquo_gr<-enquo(gr)

r<-df%>%
   dplyr::mutate(UQ(paste("CI",quo_name(gr),sep="_")):=
                   sprintf("(%s,%s)",
                           paste("CIlow",UQ(enquo_gr),sep="_"),
                           paste("CIhigh",UQ(enquo_gr),sep="_")))%>%
   dplyr::select(paste("CI",UQ(enquo_gr),sep="_"))

return(r)
}
```

However when using the above mentioned function in this way

```
library(dplyr)
group<-c("a","b")
dataframe<-data.frame(CIlow_a=c(1.1,1.2),CIlow_b=c(2.1,2.2),CIlow_c=c(3.1,3.2),CIhigh_a=c(1.3,1.4),CIhigh_b=c(2.3,2.4),CIhigh_c=c(3.3,3.4))

f(df=dataframe,gr=group)
```

I get the following error message:

> Error: `expr` must quote a symbol, scalar, or call

How could I solve this issue?

PS1: This question is similar to [a previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995997/create-a-new-variable-using-dplyrmutate-and-pasting-two-existing-variables-for). However, this question goes one step further because it requires selecting the columns to be merged.

PS2: I would appreciate code suggestions following the approach of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found by myself an solution for my issue. The code below works:

```
output<-data.frame(CI_a=c("(1.1,1.3)","(1.2,1.4)"), CI_b=c("(2.1,2.3)","(2.2,2.4)"))

dataframe<-data.frame(CIlow_a=c(1.1,1.2),CIlow_b=c(2.1,2.2),CIlow_c=c(3.1,3.2),
                      CIhigh_a=c(1.3,1.4),CIhigh_b=c(2.3,2.4),CIhigh_c=c(3.3,3.4))

f <- function(df, gr){

   sl <<-  rlang::syms(paste("CIlow", gr, sep="_"))
   sh <<-  rlang::syms(paste("CIhigh", gr, sep="_"))
   nmN <<- paste("CI", gr, sep= "_")
   r<-df

for(i in 1:length(gr)){
        r<-dplyr::mutate(r,UQ(nmN[i]) := sprintf("(%s;%s)", UQ(sl[[i]]),UQ(sh[[i]])))
}
   r<- dplyr::select(r,nmN)
return(r)

 }

group <- c("a","b")

x<-f(df=dataframe, gr=group)
```

The code works for an undefined number of elements in `group`. Thus, it works for `c("a","b")`, for `c("a")` or `c("a","b","c")`.

I know loops are not recommended. Any better solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If we are passing quoted strings, then use `sym` (for more than one element - `syms` which return a `list`)

```
f <- function(df, gr){
   sl <-  rlang::syms(paste("CIlow", gr, sep="_"))
   sh <-  rlang::syms(paste("CIhigh", gr, sep="_"))
   nmN <- paste("CI", gr, sep= "_")


   df %>%
       dplyr::mutate(!!(nmN[1]) := sprintf("(%s,%s)",
                               !!(sl[[1]]), !!(sh[[1]])),
                     !!(nmN[2]) := sprintf("(%s,%s)",
                               !!(sl[[2]]), !!(sh[[2]]))) %>%
       dplyr::select(paste("CI", gr, sep="_"))



 }

group <- c("a","b")
f(dataframe, group)
#      CI_a      CI_b
#1 (1.1,1.3) (2.1,2.3)
#2 (1.2,1.4) (2.2,2.4)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! Great solution! However, I need a script that enables an undefined number of groups. I mean, I would like to join CI sometimes for `a`, sometimes for `a` and `b`, and sometimes (why not) for `a`, `b` and `c`. You script fixes the number of groups to 2 (see `[[1]]` and `[[2]]`). I would appreciate any further idea.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work ("LHS must be a name or string) f <- function(df, gr){
   sl <-  rlang::syms(paste("CIlow", gr, sep="_"))
   sh <-  rlang::syms(paste("CIhigh", gr, sep="_"))
   nmN <- paste("CI", gr, sep= "_")


   df %>%
       dplyr::mutate(!!(nmN) := sprintf("(%s,%s)", !!(sl), !!(sh)))%>%
       dplyr::select(paste("CI", gr, sep="_"))

 }`

Comment: @ungatoverde  I tried earlier a similar approach, but it may not work.  I will check when I get some time

Answer (score 1):

I would have probably answered differently basing on the question, but after examining you answer I prepared below code. It uses trick with `lapply` from here [dplyr::unite across column patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002235/dplyrunite-across-column-patterns). I am not sure if usage of `dplyr/tidyr` is the best option here, maybe simple `for` would be simpler.

```
output <- data.frame(CI_a=c("(1.1,1.3)","(1.2,1.4)"),
                     CI_b=c("(2.1,2.3)","(2.2,2.4)"),
                     stringsAsFactors = F)

dataframe <- data.frame(CIlow_a=c(1.1,1.2),CIlow_b=c(2.1,2.2),CIlow_c=c(3.1,3.2),
                        CIhigh_a=c(1.3,1.4),CIhigh_b=c(2.3,2.4),CIhigh_c=c(3.3,3.4))


tricky <- function(input_data, group_ids){

  # convert columns to character

  input_data <- input_data %>%
    mutate_each(funs(as.character(.)))

  # unite selected groups

  output <- group_ids %>%
    lapply(function(group_id) {unite_(input_data, 
                                      paste0("CI_", group_id), 
                                      paste0(c("CIlow_", "CIhigh_"), group_id), 
                                      sep = ',') %>% select_(paste0("CI_", group_id))}) %>%
    bind_cols() %>%
    mutate_each(funs(paste0("(", ., ")")))

  return(output)

}

identical(tricky(dataframe, list("a", "b")), output)
```